# mysql partition by range on day time stamp issue

Tags: mysql

I am having issue to partition a table using partition by range on a datetime column.

the test search result is still on full partition scan.

I saw some posts on the net in regards to this issue, but not sure if there is any way to fix it or bypass the issue.

mysql server: Percona 5.5.24-55.

table:

`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`time` datatime unsigned NOT NULL,
....
....

KEY `id_time` (`id`,`time`)

engine=InnoDB

partition statement:

alter table summary_201204
partition by range (day(`time`))
subpartition by key(`id`)
subpartitions 5 (
partition p0 values less than (6),
partition p1 values less than (11),
partition p2 values less than (16),
partition p3 values less than (21),
partition p4 values less than (26),
partition p5 values less than (MAXVALUE) );

check:
explain partitions select * from summary_201204 where `time` < '2012-07-21';

result: p0_p0sp0,p0_p0sp1,p0_p0sp2,p0_p0sp3,p0_p0sp4,p1_p1sp0,p1_p1sp1,p1_p1sp2,p1_p1sp3,p1_p1sp4,p2_p2sp0,p2_p2sp1,p2_p2sp2,p2_p2sp3,p2_p2sp4,p3_p3sp0,p3_p3sp1,p3_p3sp2,p3_p3sp3,p3_p3sp4,p4_p4sp0,p4_p4sp1,p4_p4sp2,p4_p4sp3,p4_p4sp4,p5_p5sp0,p5_p5sp1,p5_p5sp2,p5_p5sp3,p5_p5sp4.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the answer: Visit [enter link description here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_55_partitioning.html)

So, the documentation within the mysql official site is not clear enough about the data types required for partition. In this case, if the table data type is datetime, then we should use to_seconds, whilst if the data type is DATE then we can use YEA